# Is it possible to find four real numbers, for which $a+b<c+d$ and $ {\rm e}^{-a} + {\rm e}^{-b} <{\rm e}^{-c} + {\rm e}^{-d} $ holds?

Tags: analysis

For those interested, this question arises because in markov random fields one encounteres a lot of algorithms which look vor variables that minimize the potential of multiple cliques. So if a variable $X$ gives the clique potentials $a$ and $b$ these algorithms would choose this over a variable $Y$ that gives clique potentials $c$ and $d$, if $a+b<c+d$.

From a probabilistic point of view, it would make more sense to choose $Y$ if
$ {\rm e}^{-a} + {\rm e}^{-b} <{\rm e}^{-c} + {\rm e}^{-d} $

Comment: Keyword is misleading, it's just analysis.

Comment: $a=1, b=1, c=0.5, d=2$

Comment: There are more examples but for any given $a,b\,$ you can choose any $c < -\log_e(e^{-a}+e^{-b})$ and any $d>a+b-c$

Comment: Thank you all very much for your answers, it really helped me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly.  You just need $c$ small and $d$ large compared to $a,b$.  Try $a=b=1,c=0,d=3$